# Why doesn't typescript warn about missing parameters in method?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I'm doing some react and I have this optional method in my Prop Interface.

```
Interface Props {
    ...
    ...
    onSort?: (a:SomeType[],b:SomeOtherType,c:string) => SomeType[]
    ...
    ...
}
```

And then I use it as such in my other component.

```
const onSort = (a:SomeType[])=> doSomething(a,SomeOtherType.value,'blah')
<Component 
    onSort={onSort}
/>
```

Why doesn't typescript complain that the method I am passing to onSort is only taking in 1 parameter instead of 3 ?

Comment: See [the function compatibility documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions) and [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters), as well as the answers to the above-linked questions.